# I'm experienced with programming but new to Javascript, can't figure out why my code won't run

Tags: javascript, oop, html5-canvas

I'm coming from a background in C++ and Java, and trying to learn Javascript and canvas.  Based off of [this tutorial](http://blog.lostdecadegames.com/how-to-make-a-simple-html5-canvas-game), I've got [this](http://codeviewer.org/view/code:1e04) so far.  What did I do wrong that is causing it not to run?  I suspect it's because I'm not understanding objects in Javascript properly.  Thanks!

Comment: You are missing two closing-braces (`}`), one at the end of each `for` statement.

Comment: @njk - Feel free to answer your own question! Then "accept" the answer to mark it as "closed".

Comment: @njk - I added a response. If it helped, please "accept" so others might benefit of it. Thanks.

Comment: JSLint is a pretty good tool that can help you catch some syntax errors. Try that out if you are struggling. It is also worth it to install Node.js just to have a nice JavaScript interactive prompt to mess around in.

Comment: @Jergason thanks, is Node.js anything like the python prompt?  Sounds cool.  I ran this through JSLint but it reported a ton of errors, is there an easy way to make it less stringent with stuff like spacing?

Viccari done and done

Seth thanks for the tip, will do!

Comment: Node.js is a framework for event-based programming in JavaScript, but it also includes a prompt. You can ignore the framework stuff if you like and just use it as a prompt. JSLint can be very grumpy about spacing, global variables, ect. You can make it less strict by tweaking the options at the bottom. Some of its suggestions are good, and some are just designed to force you to code like Douglas Crockford. Try turning off the spacing stuff, the var stuff, the 'use strict' stuff, and checking the 'assume browser' and 'assume console ect' stuff. JSHint is a less finicky version of JSLint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing two closing-braces (}), one at the end of each for statement.